# Contract Field Status/Record Type

Tags: contracts

When you are first creating a contract, you can only choose a status in the draft category. Once the contract is created you can change the status to the ones in other categories by editing it, activating it. etc.

My problem is that I want to add a Status of Expired, but I want a 4th status category too. The 3 are too limiting. I know you can add a status type of Expired but it would still be an Activated Field Status and I was hoping there was a contract record type that expired, lost, not renewed, etc could be listed under.

Go--Setup---Customize--Contract--Record type--Search for the Appropriate Record type nam---Click on it---Search for the field Status Category---Make sure the values which you have requeste are in the Selected If they are in Available values move it to Selected values.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. `Contract.Status` must exist within one of three `StatusCategory`

See [Contract Object Doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contract.htm?search_text=contract)

> The status category for the contract. A contract can be Draft, InApproval, or Activated. Label is Status Category.

The lifecycle in the real world for contracts is `Draft -> InApproval -> Activated`.

By definition, a contract can't expire until it as been activated (ie put in force between two counterparties). So the logical place for a `Status = Expired` is under Activated.  Less-is-more.

Comment: The entire first part is understood but a contract in the real world does not stay activated without an end. That specific contract comes to an end of lifecycle that would for those that expire, are lost, etc., therefore no longer active.

Comment: `activated` does not mean `active`, it means that it represents a contract that is/was in force